# Any Proper/Clean way to handle a Large number of if..then case in react table?

Tags: reactjs

i have a big drop down(100x key element) list ...and each drop down will show different table(100x Type),
so that my code would like:

```
const typeA =[
  {
    Header: "Gender",
    accessor: "_source.aa",
    className: "t-cell-1 text-left"
  },
  {
    Header: "Age",
    className: "t-cell-1 text-left",
    accessor: "lastRecord.bb"
  }
]
const typeA1 =[
  {
    Header: "Firstname",
    accessor: "_source.firstname",
    className: "t-cell-1 text-left"
  },
  {
    Header: "Lastname",
    className: "t-cell-1 text-left",
    accessor: "lastRecord.lastname"
  }
]
const typeA100 =[
  {
    Header: "Height",
    accessor: "_source.height",
    className: "t-cell-1 text-left"
  },
  {
    Header: "Weight",
    className: "t-cell-1 text-left",
    accessor: "lastRecord.weight"
  }
]
```

And in the render part i am doing this like

```
  return (
    <Styles>
:isTypeA1? <Table columns={TypeA1} data={data} /> 
:isTypeA2? <Table columns={TypeA2} data={data} />       
...
:isTypeA100? <Table columns={TypeA100} data={data} />       

    </Styles>
  )
}
```

And i would like to ask if there 's any way to shorten the line of code as the header Part is way too much code and it's very similar like in general .

Updated 20210813
the component i am using now is checkbox, and will change to drop down later,
while the code of the check box is this:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     
      isTypeA1: false,
    };
  }
  toggleCheck = () => {
    this.setState({
      isTypeA1: !this.state.isTypeA1,
    });
  }


   <div>
                  <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  name="myCheckBox1" 
                  checked={this.state.isTypeA1}
                  onClick={this.toggleCheck}
                  
                  />
                 testing chk box</div>
```

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: Where does isTypeA1 come from? typeA1, etc should be keys on an object.

Comment: could you edit the code to show the full component? Need to know where isTypeA1 and all are coming from

Comment: i have extract piece of the code in the edit, thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is the way that is most **readable** and **maintainable** and **reusable**, so it's different for every use case and every project.

One of the common patterns in your case is to make `renderTable` or whatever name seems appropriate,
And make a switch case like:

```js
const Home = ({ data, type }) => {

  const renderTable= (item) => {
    switch(type) {
      case 'A1':
        return <Table columns={TypeA1} data={data} />;
      case 'A2':
        return <Table columns={TypeA2} data={data} />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {renderTable()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But it's will be just an option depending on your use case, so feel free to edit to whatever you think better.